# Updating pyplot.vlines in interactive plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, python-interactive

I need your help. Please consider the code below, which plots a sinusoid using `pylab` in `IPython`. A slider below the axis enables the user to adjust the frequency of the sinusoid interactively.

```
%pylab
# setup figure
fig, ax = subplots(1)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

# add a slider
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
ax_freq = axes([0.3, 0.13, 0.5, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)
s_freq = Slider(ax_freq, 'Frequency [Hz]', 0, 100, valinit=a0)

# plot 
g = linspace(0, 1, 100)
f0 = 1
sig = sin(2*pi*f0*t)
myline, = ax.plot(sig)

# update plot
def update(value):
    f = s_freq.val
    new_data = sin(2*pi*f*t)
    myline.set_ydata(new_data)     # crucial line
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

s_freq.on_changed(update)
```

Instead of the above, I need to plot the signal as vertical lines, ranging from the amplitude of each point in `t` to the x-axis. Thus, my first idea was to use `vlines` instead of `plot` in line 15:

```
myline = ax.vlines(range(len(sig)), 0, sig)
```

This solution works in the non-interactive case. The problem is, `plot` returns an `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` object, which provides the `set_ydata` method to update data interactively. The  object returned by `vlines` is of type `matplotlib.collections.LineCollection` and does not provide such a method. 
My question: how do I update a `LineCollection` interactively?

Comment: Probably `set_offsets`or `set_verts`.

Comment: I could not get `set_offset` or `set_verts` to work. `set_segments` does work but you must provide it in the format of a 3D array where each element is of the form `[[x, ymin], [x, ymax]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `@Aaron Voelker`'s comment of using `set_segments` and wrapping it up in a function:

```
def update_vlines(*, h, x, ymin=None, ymax=None):
    seg_old = h.get_segments()
    if ymin is None:
        ymin = seg_old[0][0, 1]
    if ymax is None:
        ymax = seg_old[0][1, 1]

    seg_new = [np.array([[xx, ymin],
                         [xx, ymax]]) for xx in x]

    h.set_segments(seg_new)
```

Analog for `hlines`:

```
def update_hlines(*, h, y, xmin=None, xmax=None):
    seg_old = h.get_segments()
    if xmin is None:
        xmin = seg_old[0][0, 0]
    if xmax is None:
        xmax = seg_old[0][1, 0]

    seg_new = [np.array([[xmin, yy],
                         [xmax, yy]]) for yy in y]

    h.set_segments(seg_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give examples for `vlines` here.

If you have multiple lines, [@scleronomic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7570817/scleronomic) solution works perfect. You also might prefer one-liner:

```py
myline.set_segments([np.array([[x, x_min], [x, x_max]]) for x in xx])
```

If you need to update only maximums, then you can do this:

```py
def update_maxs(vline):
    vline[:,1] = x_min, x_max
    return vline

myline.set_segments(list(map(update_maxs, x.get_segments())))
```

Also this example could be useful: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252107/how-to-draw-vertical-lines-interactively-in-matplotlib)